# How to determine that a-dist is negative?

Tags: c#, trigonometry

[image]

What kind of formula I need to use that I can determine that point P3 is negative side of P1-P2 line?
//x0, y0 is point P3 and x1,y1,x2,y2 is line P1-P2

```
static double ADist(double x0,double y0,double x1,double y1,double x2,double y2)
{
    
    double Dx = (x2 - x1);
    double Dy = (y2 - y1);
                        
    double numerator = (Dy * x0 - Dx * y0 - x1 * y2 + x2 * y1);
    double denominator = Math.Sqrt(Dx * Dx + Dy * Dy);
    
    double b2 = numerator / denominator;
    double dx = x0 - x1;
    double dy = y0 - y1;
    double dxy = Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    double a = Math.Sqrt(dxy * dxy - b2 * b2);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is more math question (there is a [stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/) for that if you don't know it : you may make a scalar product (or dot product) of vectors (P1-P2) and vector (P1-P3). If dot product is negative, so it is on "negative side" ( = 0 if the vectors are perpendicular).

```
public double ScalarProduct (Vector v1,Vector v2)
{
    return v1.x*v2.x + v1.y*v2.y;
}
```

You just need to convert your points to vectors.

In your case, it would be `(dx*Dx + dy*Dy)`

Then to determinate the value of distance :

```
private double getDistance2(double x0,double y0,double x1,double y1,double x2,double y2)
{
    double A = x2 * x2 + y2 * y2;
    double B = 2 * (x1 - x0) * x2 + 2 * (y1 - y0) * y2;
    double C = (x1 - x0) * (x1 - x0) + (y1 - y0) * (y1 - y0);

    double s0 = -B / (2 * A);
    double d2 = Math.Round((A * s0 * s0 + B * s0 + C), 3);
    return Math.Sqrt(d2);
}
```

this method returns the distance between P3, and the line P1-P2.
Then you just need to calculate distance between P1 and P3, and using Pythagore you will find your distance.